# How to export Maven project with excel files and javafx in it?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, javafx

I've been searching for this issue for two days. I am building an application and I started with maven project. So now I have finished it and it runs perfectly. But the problem is there seems no way to export it as a jar file. My goal is to have an installable .exe file in the end.        The project has excel and xml files as resources and many dependencies and libraries. I managed to build a jar file successfully and I cannot run it. Here is my POM.Thank you guys

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: To be clear, are you are building this with `mvn clean assembly:directory` and running the jar file with `java -jar project/target/bin/thejarfile.jar`? Can you please include your build and run commands for us? If you're building it from Eclipse, it might just be running `mvn clean install` which won't package your JAR like you want. You can modify this in the project properties (look for Properties > Build > Run) or something like that to see the Maven commands that are run when you build it. You can't turn a JAR into an EXE without extra tools, you need to run it with `java -jar ...`

Comment: Have you looked at the [javafx-maven-plugin](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin) ?

Answer (score 0):

As matt said, you would need a 3rd party tool to wrap your jar as an exe.  I've used JSmooth before http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net

Note: this kind of kills the idea of java being platform independent.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a jar which can be executed by double click then

1. Create a manifest file like this with your main class

   > Main-Class: Main Class Name
2. Create a jar by providing this manifest file
3. Run this jar using java -jar or double click(similar to exe)

Comment: Or using something like the [javafx-maven-plugin](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin) would be an option ;) disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of that project